# Why does reading from file add an extra space to the line?

Tags: python, file, with-statement

I have this authentication.txt file where I keep username:password credentials. When I try to read them, the password happens to have an extra whitespace even though I made sure to delete the whitespaces at the end of each line.

```
with open('authentication.txt') as fp:
            for line in fp:
                username, password = line.split(":")
                credentails_dict[username] = password.strip()
```

So I strip() the password to make sure it is plain characters. I was wondering if this mistake is by me or default with open function.

Comment: `strip` will remove whitespaces at the start and end of the string. Are you sure there is a trailing whitespace? Try to `print(repr(credentails_dict[username]))` and look at the real content.

Comment: '12345\n'
'54321\n'
'abcde'            There is a newline at the end of each line. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show the sample of authentication.txt file?

Comment: It's not your fault, the TextIOWrapper readlines always convert `newlines` to platform specified line ender of each line.

Comment: You might be getting new line char

Comment: Yes, you are all correct, I am getting '\n' at the end of each line except the last one. Is there a way to read the file so the new_line character is not read?

Comment: [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) should take care of all whitespaces, including `'\n'`, `'\r'` and `'\t'`.

Comment: You can use ```password.replace("\n","")``` or ```line.replace("\n","")```

Comment: Yes, I am already using strip and will go on with it. I hope that's the best way to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: I may have misread your question. I thought you said that there is a trailing `\n` even after you used `strip`. Obviously your question is, why there is an `\n`. That's how it is (it is part of the line) and you can deal with that by using `strip` (or `rstrip` if you don't want to touch the start of the string).